# Prove that the two lines intersect orthogonally

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

Given the two curve equations are: $(x-1)^2 + y^2 = 2$  and $(x+1)^2 + y^2 = 2$, prove that the two curves intersect orthogonally, then find the equation of the tangent at the intersection points.

What I did was differentiate both equations expecting the derivatives to be reciprocals of each other resulting in a $-1$, but instead I got $\frac{dy}{dx}^1 = -\frac{x-1}{y}$ and $\frac{dy}{dx}^2 = -\frac{x+1}{y}$. What should I do now?

Comment: They can't be reciprocals everywhere. At what points do they intersect?

Comment: @Raskolnikov I don't know. I tried plotting the two equations in Wolfram Alpha and found out they intersect at (0,1) and (0,-1). But I don't exactly know how to get that answer mathematically, not graphically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to calculate the tangent slopes at the point(s) of intersection

Comment: I don't know what the points of intersection are. How do I find the points of intersection?

Comment: To prove they intersect, you have to find (x,y) that satisfies both equations. Since you have both equations arranged such that the both left-hand side equals 2, you may set the left-hand sides equal. FYI:  Do not forget that the square root of a square requires the absolute value.

Comment: Nice. You're welcome.